# How to Delete a item in Expendable ListView using Delete Button

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-2.2-froyo

I am unable to delete an item using delete button in each row of the ListView. I don't know how to get the current position of the button click of the Listview item. Can you help me out how to solve this problem .
All I want to do is that when I click delete button that particular row gets deleted.

Following are the main activity code and xml code

**My Xml code for expandable listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:slide="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test_expendable"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Create_Team_Form" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandable_toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/Team_More" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Del"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="Team_Delete"
        android:text="@string/Team_Del"
        android:textSize="12dip" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="Team_Details"
        android:text="@string/Team_Detail"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

   </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**My main activity Xml code on which I have ListView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/Team_Create_MainTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Create"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Create_Team"
                android:text="@string/Team_Create_New" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_ADD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Team_Create_Add" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Team_Create_Edit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Team_Create_Back" />

        </TableRow>




        <com.example.fyp_api_8_team.SlideExpandableListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="465dp" >

        </com.example.fyp_api_8_team.SlideExpandableListView>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My main Activity Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Create_Team_Form extends Activity {

    TextView txt;
    private String[] lv_arr = {};
    ArrayList<String> teamNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView list;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    static String[] COUNTRIES;
    //ListView lv1;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create__team__form);

        list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_create__team__form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Create_Team(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("CreateTeam");
        alert.setMessage("Enter Team Name");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // OK
                String ans = input.getText().toString();
                if (ans == null || ans.length() == 0 || ans.equals("")) {

                } else {
                    String value = ans;
                    Add_TeamName_List(value);

                    Set_List();
                }

            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

        alert.show();

    }


    public void Add_TeamName_List(String Name) {
        teamNames.add(Name);

        Put_data_Array();

    }

    public void Set_List() {
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.expandable_list_item, R.id.text, lv_arr);
        list.setAdapter(new SlideExpandableListAdapter(adapter,
                R.id.expandable_toggle_button, R.id.expandable));

        /*
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, lv_arr));
                */
    }

    public void Put_data_Array() {
        lv_arr = new String[teamNames.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < teamNames.size(); i++) {
            lv_arr[i] = teamNames.get(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(lv_arr);

        put_Data_again_Arraylist();


    }

    public void put_Data_again_Arraylist()
    {

            teamNames.clear();  
        for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++) {

            teamNames.add(lv_arr[i]);
        }

    }



    public void Team_Delete(View v)
    {

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               teamNames.remove(position);
                ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Team_Details(View v)
    {

    }
```

Below I have attached the screenshot of my UI

[image]

When I click the More button my Delete and Detail buttons are shown to the user If user Press the Delete button that row item should be deleted.

[image]

Waiting for the reply I am trying to solve this problem for quite a time now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** Always use `ArrayList` instead of `String[]` for holding the values which will be used by the `ArrayAdapter` as `Collection` are far more flexible than `Arrays`

**-** You can simply **remove** the entry from `ArrayList` on clicking the delete button, and then do the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

**Eg:**

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

s.setList();   // A custom method to fill the list

// assign your ArrayList to the ArrayAdpater here

// set ArrayAdpater to ListView

arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // arrayadapter is of the ArrayAdapter which is 
                                      // set with your ArrayList
```

Comment: the problem was that problem is that I need to resort the list when adding new item so that the list is shown alphabetic wise so i had to save the data in string den then use the Array.sort()Method to resort the list .. can your provide me a example code how to delete the item on each row button

Comment: @AftabAli You can always use Comparable Interface to sort it out, and if you want more than one way to sort it then use Comparator with the Collection.

Comment: @ kumar i sort the data using collections.sort(TeamName) but now how to delete the selected row when i click the delete button